# Ensuring client-side consistency during website deployments

Tags: web-deployment

Suppose I have a web site. Like many others, it serves up HTML pages that reference CSS and JavaScript files. I am worried about the following scenario when I deploy a new version:

1. A client loads `/index.html`.
2. My atomic, seamless deployment happens.
3. The client loads `/app.js`, which was referenced by the HTML page it loaded in step 1.

Now the client has an inconsistent view of my site: their browser has loaded an *old* version of `/index.html` and a *new* version of `/app.js`.  Then:

4. Errors ensue. The client angrily takes their dollars elsewhere.

What is the best way to avoid this scenario and ensure consistency on the client side? I'd like to guarantee that all clients see either the old or the new version of the site, not a hybrid.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find much information about this problem. There don't seem to be any strategies baked into out-of-the-box deployment solutions, nor much discussion anywhere online.

The best approach I've seen boils down to a few key ideas:

1. Static assets referenced by your HTML pages are immutable and eternal;  once you have deployed `/assets/app.js` you may never change it.
2. Deploy new versions of your assets using explicit version numbers; version 23 of your HTML website should reference only, say, `/assets/app-v23.js`.
3. If your deployment is not completely atomic, deploy in phases. In the first phase deploy all the new versions of your static assets across the fleet. These will not yet be referenced by any HTML pages, since they have a new version number. In the second phase deploy all the new versions of your HTML, referencing the new assets.

Sources:

- [Static assets in an eventually consistent webapp](https://www.rea-group.com/blog/static-assets-in-an-eventually-consistent-webapp-deployment/): discusses the problem in the original question plus additional twists when your deployments are not atomic. While the solution is overwrought, it gives some interesting ideas.
- [Stealthy shipping with atomic deploys](https://medium.com/@Pinterest_Engineering/stealthy-shipping-with-atomic-deploys-a77bf746c16d): discusses handling updates to your XHR API, which is a variant of this problem. The user's browser has an old version of your JavaScript app but might access newer versions of your API if the user does not refresh very often.